# How to fix Invalid arguments during creation of MPI derived Datatypes

Tags: debugging, compilation, runtime-error, mpi

I have one `structure xyz` as given below  `struct xyz { char a; int32_t b; char c[50]; uint32_t d; uchar e[10];}`

I need to broadcast it so I used MPI_Bcast() where i required MPI Datatype corresponding to struct xyz for that I used `MPI_Type_creat_struct()` function to create a new MPI datatype as `MPI_Datatype MPI_my_new_datatype, oldtypes[4];` where I used MPI datatypes corresponding to above structure members datatype as followings

`oldtypes[4] = {MPI_CHAR, MPI_INT, MPI_UNSIGNED, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR};` and to craete new datatype i used following arguments in the function..

`MPI_Type_create_struct(4,blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &MPI_my_new_datatype); MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_my_new_datatype);`

Now it is compiling but giving run time error as below::
 *** An error occurred in `MPI_Type_create_struct`on communicator `MPI_COMM_WORLD` `MPI_ERR_ARG`: invalid argument of some other kind  `MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL` (goodbye).

Can any one find out where is the problem?

Comment: Can you post the entire code where you define the datatype? In particular, the definition of `blockcounts` and `offsets`.

Comment: int blockcounts[4];
MPI_Aint offsets[4], extent;
offsets[0] = 0; blockcounts[0] = (1 + 50);//for char,
offsets[1] = (1 + 50) * extent; blockcounts[1] = (10); // for uchar,
offsets[1] = (10) * extent; blockcounts[1] = 1; // for int32_t,
offsets[1] = 1 * extent; blockcounts[1] = 1; // for uint32_t

Comment: @suszterpatt sir i added definition of  blockcounts and offsets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "bundle up" the similar types like that.  Each field needs to be addressed seperately, and there are 5 of them, not 4.

Also note that, in general, it's a good idea to actually "measure" the offsets rather than infer them.

The following works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct xyz_t {
    char a; int32_t b; char c[50]; uint32_t d; unsigned char e[10];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int rank, size, ierr;
    MPI_Datatype oldtypes[5] = {MPI_CHAR, MPI_INT, MPI_CHAR, MPI_UNSIGNED, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR};
    int blockcounts[5] = {1, 1, 50, 1, 10};
    MPI_Datatype my_mpi_struct;
    MPI_Aint offsets[5];

    struct xyz_t old, new;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    /* find offsets */

    offsets[0] = (char*)&(old.a) - (char*)&old;
    offsets[1] = (char*)&(old.b) - (char*)&old;
    offsets[2] = (char*)&(old.c) - (char*)&old;
    offsets[3] = (char*)&(old.d) - (char*)&old;
    offsets[4] = (char*)&(old.e) - (char*)&old;

    MPI_Type_create_struct(5, blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &my_mpi_struct);
    MPI_Type_commit(&my_mpi_struct);
    if (rank == 0) {
        old.a = 'a';
        old.b = (int)'b';
        strcpy(old.c,"This is field c");
        old.d = (unsigned int)'d';
        strcpy(old.e,"Field e");

        MPI_Send(&old, 1, my_mpi_struct, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } else if (rank == 1) {
        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Recv(&new, 1, my_mpi_struct, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("new.a = %c\n", new.a);
        printf("new.b = %d\n", new.b);
        printf("new.e = %s\n", new.e);
    }

    MPI_Type_free(&my_mpi_struct);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Running:

```
$ mpirun -np 2 ./struct
new.a = a
new.b = 98
new.e = Field e
```

**Updated**:  As  Dave Goodell below points out, the offset calculations would be better done as

```
#include <stddef.h>
/* ... */

offsets[0] = offsetof(struct xyz_t,a);
offsets[1] = offsetof(struct xyz_t,b);
offsets[2] = offsetof(struct xyz_t,c);
offsets[3] = offsetof(struct xyz_t,d);
offsets[4] = offsetof(struct xyz_t,e);
```

and if your MPI supports it (most should, though OpenMPI was slow with some of the MPI2.2 types) the `MPI_UNSIGNED` should be replaced with an `MPI_UINT32`

Comment: The `offsetof` macro is a safer way to handle those offset calculations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof.  Also, if you want to send a `uint32_t` and you have an MPI-2.2 compliant implementation then you can use the `MPI_UINT32_T` MPI predefined datatype.  There is always a risk that `sizeof(uint32_t)!=sizeof(unsigned)`.

Comment: I've used MPI_Get_address in Fortran; I don't usually use it in C since there are several other ways to do it, and I don't like to use a library call when a builtin will work, but that's just a style thing...

Comment: @JonathanDursi Sir PLease help me about the following plm......... to abort all other processes when one process finds the solution in a cluster of p processes i am using following two approaches.

first approach is to call MPI_Abort() function from a process whenever its find solution.
second approach is to use a flag and set it whenever any process find its solution. After setting this flag send it to all the other processes using non-blocking send/recv/Iprobe funtion. Then check this flag by each process using if(flag == 1) break; and do so..      which one is better and why??